# Freezing few last rows, first few columns and header of grid View

Tags: c#, gridview

Please suggest any workaround to freez the last 4 rows of my Grid View.

I have successfully freezed the header row and left 2 columns. And as per the requirement I need to freez the last 4 row also.

Freezing last 4 rows of grid View

Comment: when you say freezing? do you mean read only? or not to scroll?

Comment: How did you do it for the first rows?

Comment: show us some code, perhaps that way we can help you?!

Comment: when you say freezing? do you mean read only? or not to scroll? – CR41G14 -------------------------------------------------------------- Freezing means - Not to scroll.. I want last rows at the bottom only when I scroll the grid vertically

Comment: How did you do it for the first rows? – Amiram Korach -----------------Hi, I have added these css class to First row and every first two columns of the grid .frozenCell  {
    text-align: center;
          position:relative;
    cursor: default;    
    left: expression(document.getElementById("divID").scrollLeft-2);
    }
    .frozenHeader
    {               border-right: 1px solid black;
        position:relative;
        cursor: default;
        top: expression(document.getElementById("divID").scrollTop-2);
        z-index : 10;
    }

Comment: show us some code, perhaps that way we can help you?! – Sylca  I have just added a GridView and top of that there one div which is scrollable. and based on above css posted i am able to freez first two columns and header row. But I want to freez the last 4 rows now

Comment: Html
--------
<div style="overflow:scroll; width:99%;height:250px" id="divDataGrid">
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewBalances" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" Height="120%" CssClass="scroll" 
            onrowdatabound="GridViewBalances_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
</div>

Comment: Code Behind
-------------
RowDatabound event
e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "locked";
            e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = "locked";
            e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "locked";
            e.Row.Cells[3].CssClass = "locked";
            e.Row.Cells[4].CssClass = "locked";

Answer (score 0):

## CSS

```
.frozenFooter
{
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: Green;
    color: Black;
    position: relative;
    bottom:expression(getScrollBottom(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode));
}

.frozenCell  {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
background-color: Gray;
color:Black ;
border-right: 1px solid silver;
position:relative;
cursor: default;
/*IE5+ only*/
/*left: expression(document.getElementById("div-datagrid").scrollLeft-2);*/
/*left:expression((this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.scrollLeft-2)+'px');*/

left: expression(document.getElementById("pnlContainer").scrollLeft-2);
}
.lockedForLastRow  {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
background-color: Gray;
color:Black ;
border-right: 1px solid silver;
position:relative;
cursor: default;
/*IE5+ only*/
/*left: expression(document.getElementById("div-datagrid").scrollLeft-2);*/
/*left:expression((this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.scrollLeft-2)+'px');*/

left: expression(document.getElementById("pnlContainer").scrollLeft-2);
}
.frozenHeader
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: Green;
    color:Black ;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
    cursor: default;
    top: expression(document.getElementById("pnlContainer").scrollTop-2);
    z-index : 10;
}

</style>
```

## Script

function getScrollBottom(p_oElem)
        {

         return p_oElem.scrollHeight - p_oElem.scrollTop - p_oElem.clientHeight;
        }

## HTML

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        Width="96%"  ShowFooter="false" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C1") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                C1 Footer Here
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C2") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                C2 Footer Here
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C3") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                C3 Footer Here
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C4">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C4") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                C4 Footer Here
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C5">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C5") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                C5 Footer Here
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C6">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C6") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                C6 Footer Here
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C7">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C7") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                C7 Footer Here
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C8">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C8") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                C8 Footer Here
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C9">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C9") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                C9 Footer Here
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="C10">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("C10") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                C10 Footer Here
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

```
    </asp:GridView>

</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("C1");
    dt.Columns.Add("C2");
    dt.Columns.Add("C3");
    dt.Columns.Add("C4");
    dt.Columns.Add("C5");
    dt.Columns.Add("C6");
    dt.Columns.Add("C7");
    dt.Columns.Add("C8");
    dt.Columns.Add("C9");
    dt.Columns.Add("C10");
    DataRow drRow;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        drRow = dt.NewRow();
        drRow[0] = "C10000000" + i;
        drRow[1] = "C20000000" + i;
        drRow[2] = "C30000000" + i;
        drRow[3] = "C40000000" + i;
        drRow[4] = "C50000000" + i;
        drRow[5] = "C60000000" + i;
        drRow[6] = "C70000000" + i;
        drRow[7] = "C80000000" + i;
        drRow[8] = "C90000000" + i;
        drRow[9] = "C100000000" + i;
        dt.Rows.Add(drRow);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.Rows[9].Cells[0].ID = "footerCell";
    GridView1.Rows[9].Attributes.Add("class", "frozenFooter");
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "frozenCell";
}
```

Comment: Only there is one problem which I am facing currently is when we scroll vertically in the anywhere except the last position of the vertical bar, first cell of the freeze footer does not get locked. Other than this cell all the left columns are freeze in all the scenario

Answer (score 0):

Another Css for only for the first cell(which is freezed for left scroll) of the last row which is freezed as footer

```
.GVFixedFooterFirstCell
{ 
    font-weight:bold; 
    background-color: Green; 
    color: Black;
    position: relative;
    bottom: expression(document.getElementById("pnlContainer").scrollHeight - document.getElementById("pnlContainer").scrollTop - document.getElementById("pnlContainer").clientHeight);
    left: expression(document.getElementById("pnlContainer").scrollLeft-2);
    z-index:10;
}
```